# Save groupedby items to different excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I have a excel file that I want to group based on the Column name 'Step No.' and want the corresponding value.Here is a piece of code I wrote :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fpath=('/Users/Anil/Desktop/Test data.xlsx')
df=pd.read_excel(fpath)
data=df.loc[:,['Step No.','Parameter','Values']]
grp_data=pd.DataFrame(data.groupby(['Step No.','Values']).size().reset_index())
grp_data.to_excel('/Users/Anil/Desktop/Test1 data.xlsx')
```

The data gets grouped just as I want it to.

```
Step No.    Values
    1            62
    1            62.5
    1            63
    1            66.5
    1            68
    1            70
    1            72
    1            76.5
    1            77
    2            66.5
    2            67
    2            69
    3            75.5
    3            77
```

But, I want data corresponding to each Step No. in a different excel sheet, i.e all values corresponding to Step No.1 in one sheet, Step No. 2 in another sheet and so on. I think I should use some sort of iteration, but don't know what kind exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter

steps = df['Step No.'].unique()
dfs = [df.loc[df['Step No.']==step] for step in steps]
def save_xls(list_dfs, xls_path):
    writer = ExcelWriter(xls_path)
    for n, df in enumerate(list_dfs):
        df.to_excel(writer,'sheet%s' % n)
    writer.save()
save_xls(dfs, 'YourFile.xlsx')
```

Comment: I tried your solution. But, there is an error 'method object is not iterable' for '[df.loc[df['Step No.']==step] for step in steps]'. 
I think the code should be:
 steps=df['Step No.'].unique()

Comment: Yeah, `unique` is method and should be called. Edited.